# Xcode 11 Segmentation fault: 11 during Archive

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm receiving a segmentation fault in Xcode 11 when I do an Archive of Generic iOS Device. The file this apparently is occurring in, "InformationMenu", hasn't been touched in months so I have no idea what's causing this.

I've tried making changes to the Optimization Level with no luck. The app builds on devices and simulators which makes this all the more frustrating.

Everything is written in Swift 4, target is iOS 11 and above.

Not sure where to go from here.

```
InformationMenu.bc 
1.  While running pass #111377 SILModuleTransform "OwnershipModelEliminator".
0  swift                    0x0000000110142eb3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x0000000110142686 SignalHandler(int) + 358
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6b1b3b5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib   0x00007fff6b174401 tiny_malloc_should_clear + 256
4  swift                    0x000000010c4d1cbb (anonymous namespace)::OwnershipModelEliminator::run() + 267
5  swift                    0x000000010c441849 swift::SILPassManager::execute() + 7305
6  swift                    0x000000010c445c1b swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 2539
7  swift                    0x000000010c09de06 swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 70
8  swift                    0x000000010bd99ae5 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 33925
9  swift                    0x000000010bd8de54 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6820
10 swift                    0x000000010bd1b3c3 main + 1219
11 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6afc83d5 start + 1
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00000000000001ab start + 2500034007
```

Comment: The usual approach in these situations is (sorry about this): trial and error. You just remove code and see if the crash occurs, until you find where the problem is. Then you report a bug, because this crash should not be occurring.

Comment: I've commented out ALL the code for this file and it still faults with the same error. And when I change the name of the file it gives me the same fault but with the new name! How can a file that has all code commented out be causing this?

Comment: Comment out all the code and then quit Xcode and delete the DerivedData folder. Does that fix it?

Comment: Now it looks like the same error but it's moved onto another file I haven't touched in months as being the problem. I also tried Xcode 11.1 beta. Same problem. Really seems I'm out of options here!
1. While running pass #110417 SILModuleTransform "OwnershipModelEliminator".
0  swift                    0x0000000108310eb3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51

Comment: First time doing that. I'll post how it goes here. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Good luck! Sorry not to have any better suggestions :(

Comment: Hey @Joe Same problem here... how have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I ended up contacting Xcode support. There was a bug in the compiler. Something completely unrelated to what was crashing. It was never really clear what the problem was, I just shuffled some things around on advice from support and it started working.